# Handling both tap and scroll in CollectionView

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm trying to handle a tap gesture so that when I tap on the CollectionView, it will display a toast. However when I add `TapGestureRecognizer`, it blocks me from scrolling the collection. I want that it can both scroll and tap to open something. Here's my code so far:

View:

```
<CollectionView 
                x:Name="eventsBox"
                ItemsSource="{Binding EventList}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                Header="Events"
                ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView">
                <CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Command="{Binding EventBoxTapCommand}"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                        Direction="Up"
                        Swiped="EventBoxSwiped"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                        Direction="Down"
                        Swiped="EventBoxSwiped"/>
                </CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
                
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Event">
                        <HorizontalStackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EventDescription}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EventTime, StringFormat=' at {0}'}"/>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Code behind for Swipe gesture recognizer

```
    private void EventBoxSwiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Direction)
        {
            case SwipeDirection.Up:
                Console.WriteLine("Swiped Up"); 
                //Custon scroll here?
                break;

            case SwipeDirection.Down:
                Console.WriteLine("Swiped Down");
                //Custom scroll here?
                break;
        }
    }
```

I'm thinking of programmatically scroll by recognizing swipe gesture but I haven't found a way to do it. Moreover, the recognition of both tap and swipe is sometime really not responsive.

Comment: CollectionView has built in scrolling and tap handlers, why do you need to have custom ones?

Comment: Can you elaborate? My goal for tapping is to tap anywhere on the CollectionView and it will open st rather than tap to select an item. Therefore I use TapGestureRecognition. But with this the scrolling does not work

Comment: @TốngViệtDũng he is not talking about the tap. This custom swipe is making very little sense. I can assure you, I am using tap in 99.99% of my CollectionView controls. I do not even remember implementing one without tap in my last project. It is something else that is causing your problems. This swipe recognizer for example.

Comment: Also, I forgot to tell you. There is issue right now with swipes. It is really tricky to start them working. So if you decide to make some custom control, expect problems. Also, Tap will fire even if you expect something else, like pan for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Jason's comment, I came up with a work-around to achieve the effect I want.
I added `SelectionMode=Single` to the CollectionView and changed the background color of selected item matching the theme color of the app with `VisualStateManager`. Therefore it appears that no item is selected but still get the tap and scroll event.

```
<CollectionView 
                x:Name="eventsBox"
                ItemsSource="{Binding EventList}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectItemCommand}"
                Header="Events"
                ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Event">
                        <HorizontalStackLayout>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark=Black, Light=White}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EventDescription}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EventTime, StringFormat=' at {0}'}"/>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Thanks everyone for the help and information xD

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue tracked in [Gesture Recognizer Inhibits CollectionView Scrolling](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10213).You can follow up there or create a [new one](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) on Github.

To fix the issue, you can try to add a [ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview?view=net-maui-7.0) outside of the `CollectionView` like below. Also, it is recommended to add `Left`& `Right` direction of the swipe gesture in a `CollectionView`.

```
<ScrollView>
       <CollectionView> 
                <CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Command="{Binding EventBoxTapCommand}"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                        Direction="Left"
                        Swiped="EventBoxSwiped"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                        Direction="Right"
                        Swiped="EventBoxSwiped"/>
                </CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
                
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Event">
                        <VerticalStackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EventDescription}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EventTime, StringFormat=' at {0}'}"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the scrollview does not work for me. I'm trying a work-around.